# Magento 2.2.5: Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Invalid return type

Tags: magento2.2, factory

i'm doing update "students" on magento 2.2.5
and i'm stuck in how to get student data by id

the error say:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Invalid return type
```

here is my code:

```
<?php

namespace Fudu\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Student;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Fudu\HelloWorld\Model\StudentsFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class Update extends Action
{

/**
 * @var StudentsFactory
 */
protected $studentsFactory;

public function __construct(
    Action\Context $context,
    StudentsFactory $studentsFactory
)
{
    $this->studentsFactory = $studentsFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

/**
 *  Load Student data by given Student Id
 *
 * @return $student
 * @throws NoSuchEntityException
 */

public function execute()
{

    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $student = $this->studentsFactory->create();
    $student->load($id);

    return $student;
}
}
```

Comment: I think issue is with returning $student object. I am not sure but it may be throwing error because you are returning object through controller.

Comment: i delete the * return $student in " /**
 *  Load Student data by given Student Id
 *
 * return $student
 * throws NoSuchEntityException
 */ " 
but doesn't work too

Comment: what error you are getting after removing it ?

Comment: the same as before

Comment: wait , did you say i cant return something from a controller?

Comment: I mean you can't return student type of object from controller I think this can be issue.

Comment: Check my answer for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn out i cant use controller to return a object, and i have to use block to do that.
so my block is

```
 public function getStudentById(){
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $student = $this->_studentsFactory->create();
    $student->load($id);
    return $student;
}
```

and then in my phtml file

```
<?php /** @var Fudu\HelloWorld\Block\Adminhtml\StudentsBlock $block */ ?>
<form action="<?php echo $block->getPostUpdateStudentsUrl() ?>" method="post"
      style="border: 1px solid black; width: 200px; height: 250px; padding-left:10px;">

    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name" required value=<?php echo $block->getStudentById()->getName() ?>>
    <br>

    Class:<br>
    <input type="number" name="class_id" value=<?php echo $block->getStudentById()->getName() ?>>
    <br>

    Gender:<br>
    <input type="text" name="gender" value=<?php echo $block->getStudentById()->getName() ?>>
    <br>

    Age:<br>
    <input type="number" name="age" value=<?php echo $block->getStudentById()->getName() ?>>
    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

thanks all for your help.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/132798)

Comment: its the final answer here

Answer (score 3):

Reason for error is you can not return Object type of `Fudu\HelloWorld\Model\StudentsFactory` In controller execute method.

Return type for controller should be :

- **“Json” result** (return json type of data)
- **“Raw” result** (plain string)
- **“Forward”** result   ($result->forward('noroute'); )
- **“Redirect”** result   (    $result->setPath('');)

You can read more on it [source](https://alanstorm.com/magento-2-controller-result-objects/)

Comment: if it worked you can accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

`@return $student` to `@return Fudu\HelloWorld\Model\Students`

```
/**
 *  Load Student data by given Student Id
 *
 * @return Fudu\HelloWorld\Model\Students
 * @throws NoSuchEntityException
 */

public function execute()
{

    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $student = $this->studentsFactory->create();
    $student->load($id);

    return $student;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you asking to change ?

Comment: Magento cannot defined `$student` type. `@return` can be `define type (string, int, array,..)` or `model object` with full path.

Comment: you can find return type `\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\..` for controller.